# setting up an email server

Tags: smtp, webmail, email

i'm about to stop using gmail apps premium and i'm looking at using hmailserver and either zimbra or roundcube as the front end.

My question is this: does hmailserver fit well with zimbra or roundcube or should i be looking to use zimbra server with their front end?

Unless someone knows of a better server/UI combo that will run on windows?

w://

Comment: what are your reasons for moving off of google apps?

Comment: it is a doop - i read the comment on so and thought it was a better place ot have it here, then the admins moved the original after i'd asked the q :s

Comment: My reasons for moving off goog apps is that premium cost £30 per year per user, it's a bit of a pain not having 100% control to just add/remove users at will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which MTA (Mail Transport Agent) you use should have no bearing on your choice of MUA (mail user agent) although note that the MTA typically needs an additional component to route receiving mails to the MUA (a delivery agent/pop/imap server).

Although it was some time ago, I did some research using real systems to measure effectiveness of different MTAs (just looking at how often they failed to process a message as expected). Most of the MSWindows products came out with very poor scores (including MSExchange). Novell Groupwise, Sendmail and Postfix were the best (Exim, qmail and various others in between). Apart from Sendmail (we didn't look at the underlying OS) Ipswitch was the best MTA which only runs on Microsoft.

Either hmailserver did not exist at that time or was not in widespread use (we were measuring real traffic).

Your problem is that, at the bottom end of the market / freeware / open-source products for Microsoft, its rather difficult to differentiate between bundled systems built around standard components and bespoke software. hmailserver might well be running sendmail as the MTA!

Based on the fact that Zimbra [seems to use Postfix](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_MTA) as the MTA, and the fact that there are a lot of people using Postfix (and there are plugins for Anti-virus, phishing, spam) it looks like a much more attractive option than hmailserver.

NB I don't have any evidence to suggest that hmailserver is bad, just that I have a lot to suggest that postfix is good.

Comment: hmailserver is relatively new. I think it may even be an open source project.

Comment: Zimbra being a bundled package the MTA and MUA and most certainly related.

With Zimbra I don't think it's possible to swapout postfix for hmailserver.

Answer (score 0):

roundcube should work with every good imap server.

Comment: got any good examples of imap servers?

Comment: i really like dovecot. its fast, and works without too much configuration.

Comment: i cant get roundcube to install... keep running into sql errors, php errors, install errors :(

Answer (score 0):

Any of the webmail UIs should be fine with hmailserver as long as the standard IMAP/POP/SMTP protocols are used across the configuration.